# Is there a way to forward graphical windows via SSH from a headless box?

Tags: linux

I'm fairly unfamiliar with Linux, so I'm not sure if what I'm describing is possible, or even how to describe it in a way that Google will understand.

Right now, I am using my Windows PC to ssh into a headless Ubuntu Server VM. To edit files on it, I am using Sublime Text on Windows to edit files in a Samba-shared folder, and then running them on the VM. It's a little clumsy.

What I'm wondering now is if there's a way I could install Sublime Text in the VM, and then forward its GUI through SSH somehow, so that I could interact with it from Windows.

Yes, I could just use a VM that wasn't headless... but I'm wondering if something like this is possible, it would feel more natural and convenient and I wouldn't have to render an entire composited desktop.

Comment: You can achieve something similar by using TightVNC. It will create virtual screen and you'll be able to interact with it using any VNC client.

Comment: Would X-forwarding fulfill your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use X Forwarding for this, it forwards the application's GUI to a local X server running on your Windows box. For this you'll need Putty, Xming and a properly configured SSHd.

On the server, you'll need to make sure that `X11Forwarding` has been set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`.

After this, you need to run Xming to create the local X server, use PuTTY to SSH into the server with X11 Forwarding enabled in the settings, and after this, you can run the desired application, e.g. `sublime-text &`.

For a more thorough explanation, see [this](http://itg.chem.indiana.edu/inc/wiki/software/openssh/200.html) for the server side and [this](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html) for the client side.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, works perfectly and was much simpler than I thought, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can accomplish this using one of several [Windows-based X-Window servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453/what-is-a-good-and-free-x-server-for-windows). (I'm really enjoying MobaXterm currently).

The fact that the VM is "headless" is irrelevant, so long as all the required packages are installed on the VM.